# Select last row of MySQL table and edit and change its boolean value

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for the correct way to go about selecting the last row of a table and then change a value of a column(boolean) to true.

I am unsure if it is possible if you can do it with one PDO query or not.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET col = true ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Thanks sean! Its the correct answer that I was looking for thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does last row means? Implicit row order is set on pk per default so order by your pkrow desc should be ok

```
UPDATE mytable
SET myField = 'TheVal'
ORDER by id desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You might query the last row within this

> SELECT * FROM `myfield` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0,1

After that you check on your page or your stored procedure after that you update within the update syntax.

Comment: I found the correct answer above. But thank you for your effort :)